# PatchResourceNotFound error while calling azure rest API

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-log-analytics

when i am calling below log alerts azure rest api able to enable/disable only application insights) same api when calling alerts created on log analytics its throwing error "PatchResourceNotFound"

https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/subid/resourcegroups/RGname/providers/microsoft.insights/scheduledQueryRules/alertname?api-version=2018-04-16

got below error

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "PatchResourceNotFound",
    "message": "The resource 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/4776c051-f4ef-4a30-8ce7-c9fb99ff0fc5/resourcegroups/DevOpsTestRG-A/providers/microsoft.insights/scheduledQueryRules/Unexpected shutdown?api-version=2018-04-16' was not found when performing the PATCH operation."
  }
}
```

```
Disable-LogAnalyticsAlertRule {
    param(
        [Parameter(Position = 0, mandatory = $true)]
        [string] $Rulename,
        [Parameter(Position = 1, mandatory = $true)]
        [string] $ResourceGroupName
    )

    $headers = Get-AccessTokenFromContext
    $cur_sub = (Get-AzureRmContext).Subscription.Id
    $ruleUri = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$cur_sub/resourcegroups/$resourceGroupName/providers/microsoft.insights/scheduledQueryRules/$RuleName" + "?api-version=2018-04-16"
    $bodyEnable = "
{
    'properties': {
    'enabled': 'false'
    }
}
"
    Write-Verbose "ResourceURI being invoked: $ruleUri"
    try {
        $disablerule = Invoke-RestMethod -Method PATCH -Uri $ruleUri -Headers $headers -Body $bodyEnable
        $disablerule | Select-Object @{Name = "displayName"; Expression = { $_.properties.displayName } }, @{Name = "IsEnabled"; Expression = { $_.properties.enabled } }, @{Name = "lastUpdate"; Expression = { $_.properties.lastUpdatedTime } }, @{Name = "provisioningState"; Expression = { $_.properties.provisioningState } } | Format-Table -AutoSize -Wrap
        Write-Verbose "Output of Invoke-RestMethod: $disablerule"
    }
    catch {
        Write-Error "$_"
    }
}
```

Comment: you have space in resource name? you'd need to replace it with something, like `%20` or `-`?

Answer (score 1):

As per the error message, I think the comment is right: you should escape the white space in your alert name with %20, the url looks like this: https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/your_sub/resourcegroups/your_groupResource/providers/microsoft.insights/scheduledQueryRules/Unexpected%20shutdown?api-version=2018-04-16

Here is an quick way, which can provide correct url：

Nav to the [rest api page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/scheduledqueryrules/update), click on the `try it` button, and then fill in all the neccessary information, then it will auto generate a correct url which you can copy it for your usage in powershell:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response i have tried with multiple alerts with out spaces its working when disabling or enabling application in sight alerts where as for log analytics alerts its giving  error "PatchResourceNotFound",

Comment: i have tried with azure portal as shown in screenshot there also its working for application insight alerts same error for logalerts created via log analytics

Comment: when ever trying get all alert rules(including loganalytics) i am able to get "Get-LogAnalyticsAlertRule"

Comment: @DevReddy, can you please update your question with how do you create the log analytics alert? some screenshots would be better. I tested with my log analytics alert, no errors.

Comment: below link might helpful

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/pull/3112/commits/2e4c790d16eb6be9299db7a75798bca1697fd5e9#diff-405931c08436c3dfb1d6062915fcaa28

Comment: @DevReddy, what do you mean :)?

Comment: currently i am able struggling with 2 things from the above mentioned restapi i can enable or disable only 1 alert at a time, but my actual requirement is disable all alerts at once in a resource group

Comment: Other one is i have created alerts via log analytics work space and application insights, with the below script i am able to ebanle/disable alerts(Failrate 10 marked in green on below screenshot) which are created on application insights, when trying same script to disable alerts created on loganalytics i am getting error (alerts marked as red in screenshot) i have shared error above "code": "PatchResourceNotFound",

Comment: its not able to fetch the resource so its giving resource not found error

Comment: @DevReddy, ok, I don't know what's wrong your side. I did not get errors when operates alert of log analytics.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Get-AccessTokenFromContext
    {
    try {
        $accesstoken = (New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Common.RMProfileClient([Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.AzureRmProfileProvider]::Instance.Profile)).AcquireAccessToken((Get-AzureRmContext).Subscription.TenantId).AccessToken
        $buildheaders = @{
            'Authorization' = "Bearer $accesstoken"
            'Content-Type' = "application/json"
                    }
        return $buildheaders
        }
    catch
        {
            Write-Output "No context found! Please run 'Login-AzureRMAccount' to login to Azure"
            break
        }
    }
```

function Get-LogAnalyticsAlertRule
    {
    param(
     $cur_sub = 'YoursubID',
     $resourceGroupName = 'RG name'
         )
        $headers = Get-AccessTokenFromContext
        $cur_sub = (Get-AzureRmContext).Subscription.Id
        $ruleidURI = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$cur_sub/providers/microsoft.insights/scheduledQueryRules" + "?api-version=2018-04-16"
        $sqrs = (Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET $ruleidURI -Headers $headers).value
        #$sqrs | Select-Object @{Name="DisplayName";Expression={$*.properties.displayname}},@{Name="IsEnabled";Expression={$*.properties.enabled}}, @{Name="LastModified";Expression={$*.properties.lastUpdatedTime}},@{Name="Workspace";Expression={[regex]::Match($*.properties.source.dataSourceId,"(?<=/workspaces/)(.*)").value}},@{Name="Resource Group";Expression={[regex]::Match($_.properties.source.dataSourceId,"(?<=/resourceGroups/)(.*)(?=/providers)").value}} | Format-Table
        $sqrs | Select-Object name, @{Name="DisplayName";Expression={$*.properties.displayname}},@{Name="IsEnabled";Expression={$*.properties.enabled}},@{Name="Workspace";Expression={[regex]::Match($*.properties.source.dataSourceId,"(?<=/workspaces/)(.*)").value}},@{Name="Resource Group";Expression={[regex]::Match($*.properties.source.dataSourceId,"(?<=/resourceGroups/)(.*)(?=/providers)").value}} | Format-Table -AutoSize -Wrap

```
    $sqrs_prop = $sqrs.properties

    $rule_name_list = $sqrs_prop.DisplayName
    foreach($rule_name in $rule_name_list){
        Write-Host "disabling $rule_name"
        if($rule_name -ne $null){

        $ruleUri = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$cur_sub/resourcegroups/$resourceGroupName/providers/microsoft.insights/scheduledQueryRules/$rule_name"+"?api-version=2018-04-16"
         $bodyEnable = "
         {
             'properties': {
               'enabled': 'false'
             }
           }
         "
         Write-Verbose "ResourceURI being invoked: $ruleUri"

        try {
            $disablerule = Invoke-RestMethod -Method PATCH -Uri $ruleUri -Headers $headers -Body $bodyEnable
            $disablerule | Select-Object @{Name="displayName";Expression={$_.properties.displayName}}, @{Name="IsEnabled";Expression={$_.properties.enabled}},@{Name="lastUpdate";Expression={$_.properties.lastUpdatedTime}}, @{Name="provisioningState";Expression={$_.properties.provisioningState}} | Format-Table -AutoSize -Wrap
            Write-Verbose "Output of Invoke-RestMethod: $disablerule"
             }
          catch
             {
                Write-Error "$_"
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Get-LogAnalyticsAlertRule

Comment: I have created new log alert and able to enable or disable with above script with that my problem solved, but i am not able to perform any actions on the alerts which are created while back(alerts created before migrating workspace to LogAnalyticsAlertsNewAPI) after migrating not able to perform any actions on those alerts is there any limitation on that?

Comment: @Ivan Yang thanks for the help so far i have found who exactly i was blocked these days, if we try to disable/enable alerts created before migration of work space to "LogAnalyticsAlertsNewAPI", you cannot diable/enable  alerts migration when trying to get loganalytics alerts rule(Get-LogAnalyticsAlertRule) output showing GUID for alerts which are created before migration if we create any new alert after migration its not giving any error PFA link for screenshot  https://ibb.co/tDLgcX8